# noise removal in AudioRecorder

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing

i used AudioRecorder to record a chirp signal of 50 milliseconds (10-12KHz frequency).
In a calm room, at a distance of 50/60 cm, the signal spectrogram looks like this

[image]

Lots of noise in the background, and some echos.
I want to know if there's a way to reduce noise in background using Android?

**EDIT**

i tried Android `NoiseSuppressor` but it  says my device does not support this feature, though i have a 4.4 Android phone  (Nexus 4)

the cross correlation output :
[image]

Comment: Looks pretty good to me - some mic hiss, perhaps; some nonlinearity in the speaker, some reverb.  Why do you want to remove the noise?  If you want it to look like a clean chirp, maybe just threshold the energy (set low-energy spectrogram cells to zero)? "Lots" of background noise is possibly a function of the colormap scale used in the spectrogram.

Comment: i dont think it is due to colormap scale, because when i cross correlate two signals like this, i can clearly see noise peaks, and make it hard to choose the correlation peak.

Comment: It looks to me that cross-correlation should work very well on this signal.  Can we see the cross-correlation outputs?  Did you get the reference signal in the correct time order?  Are the sampling rates matched?

Comment: i added the cross correlation. the highest peak corresponds to the real delay, but what i want to know is how to "filter" the other peaks around, (while recording).

Comment: "Filtering" ultimately comes down to implementing a rule for distinguishing "what you want" from "what you don't" - but first you have to write that rule.  So what is different about the desired vs. undesired data?  If they are acoustic echoes in the same frequency range, then it may indeed be that what tells them apart is that the desired peak is the strongest - in which case you can't really filter in the frequency domain before correlation, rather you run the correlation and pick the peak result, ignoring the others.

Comment: But the problem is this recording was in a relatively quiet room. and as you can see the energy of the chirp is not that high. if there are some real noises like people talking or TV... it would be worse and may give the wrong peak. I thought i could filter just after recording, or maybe amplify the signal. but i dont really know if its possible in Android or java.

Comment: The cross-correlation output doesn't look right to me; I don't think the problem is the noise you see in the spectrogram.  Can we see a spectrogram of what you're correlating against?  And what does the correlation look like if you use the original, uncorrupted signal as input?  Time axis labels would be good, too.

Comment: the other signal is a delayed recorded version of this one. So it mainly has the same spectrogram considering that i used the same AudioRecorder. I tried using the original, the peak is very clear and there are so few peaks with very low amplitude.

Answer (score 2):

to remove noise you can try build a denoise algorithm, the main steps are:

1. Choose your frame size (2048 is nice)
2. Choose your overlap/hop size (256, 512, 1024)
3. Choose Denoise thresholds( 1, 50, 100, etc)
4. Build a raised cosine window (Hann window)
5. Apply Window in your frame
6. Shift zero frequencies to center of spectrum (Circular Shift)
7. apply FFT
8. Get the Magnitude
9. Apply denoise `denoised=(FFT * (magnitude / (magnitude+sqrt(denoise_threshold)))`
10. Back your signal to time domain  `Tdomain=real(ifft(denoised))`
11. Shift zero frequencies to center of spectrum
12. Apply Window
13. Apply Overlap and add

Comment: Thank you. On what basis should i choose denoise thresholds?

Comment: you need test differents thresholds and see what is better for you :-), here i test randon noise and white noise and thresholds = 50 works nice...

Comment: ok :) Im sorry im asking too much but does this include the echos too?